# What does か mean here?

Tags: particle-か

> 二度と来る**か**こんな病院!!

The character is an old man who is angry. He's not going to go in that hospital once again. Why doesn't he say 来ない?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This か is a question marker, and the sentence is a rhetorical question to emphasize the sentence. It literally means "Will I come", but actually means "I'll never come (again)".

This is one of the common usages of か (or かよ). Similar examples:

- 「食べる？」「食べるか(よ)！」
  "Wanna eat it?" "No way!"
- 知るか(よ)！
  Who knows! / I don't give a damn!
- 出来るか(よ)！
  No way (I can do it)!
- そんなわけあるか(よ)!
  That's impossible/nonsense!

Comment: It's possible in English to imply a question with tone of voice and in turn intend the question to be rhetorical; but for us the implication is usually a *positive* answer, I think.